# Need some tips on jQuery code optimization

Tags: jquery

Iam trying to reduce the code of my rating component which is made with html, css and jquery. I've managed to reduce it alot already but there is one piece I cant make generic.

Here do you see the HTML which I want to be able to use multiple times

```
<div class="col-control description">
 <fieldset class="rating-fieldset">
  <legend class="sr-only">Rating</legend>
   <div class="rating-container">
    <div class="rating">
     <span class="hover-score-label hide" dir="ltr"></span>
     <span class="click-score hide" dir="ltr"></span>
     <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="star5" name="rating" value="5"><label for="star5" class="star5" title="5"><span>★</span></label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="star4" name="rating" value="4"><label for="star4" class="star4" title="4"><span>★</span></label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="star3" name="rating" value="3"><label for="star3" class="star3" title="3"><span>★</span></label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="star2" name="rating" value="2"><label for="star2" class="star2" title="2"><span>★</span></label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="star1" name="rating" value="1"><label for="star1" class="star1" title="1"><span>★</span></label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </fieldset>
 </div>
```

Here do you see the jQuery which I want to optimize.

```
$('.rating label').hover(function () {
    $(this).parents('div.rating').find('.hover-score-label').removeClass("hide");

    if (!$(this).parents('div.rating').find('.hover-score-label').hasClass("hide")) {
        $(".click-score").addClass("hide");
    }
    else {
        $(".click-score").removeClass("hide");
    }

}, function () {
    $(".click-score.scored").removeClass("hide")
    $(".hover-score-label").addClass("hide");
});

$(".rating label").eq(0).hover(function () {
    $(this).parents('div.rating').find('.hover-score-label').text("5")
});


$(".rating label").eq(1).hover(function () {
    $(this).parents('div.rating').find('.hover-score-label').text("4")
});

$(".rating label").eq(2).hover(function () {
    $(this).parents('div.rating').find('.hover-score-label').text("3")
});


$(".rating label").eq(3).hover(function () {
    $(this).parents('div.rating').find('.hover-score-label').text("2")
});

$(".rating label").eq(4).hover(function () {
    $(this).parents('div.rating').find('.hover-score-label').text("1")
});
```

I hoped that it would work with the eq() but it doesnt... When I use the exact same html for the rating (See HTML part) twice on a page, the ".rating label" are not eq(0) till eq(4) but eq(5) till eq(9).

I notice i'm having a hard time to explain exactly what I want. I hope it is clear enough for you to understand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please fiddle?

Comment: @Jens it does not work when you create 2 "rating systems" (duplicate the whole fieldset element). That's what the OP explained at the end of his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your `hover` logic is a little odd, you first remove the `hide` class, then check that it's not on the element before adding it back on again...? I presume this is an attempt to toggle the class, so you can just use `toggleClass()` with no `if` condition at all. All that said, using a `hide` class is a little redundant. Just use `hide()` or `show()` as needed.

Secondly, `closest()` is preferred over the use of `parents()` in this case as it stops traversing up the DOM when the first match is found.

You can also merge the two hover events in to one as they are on the same element. You don't need a handler per-element. I did have to move the `hover-score-label` element underneath the stars, otherwise the showing/hiding of the element interfered with the hover events.

As you want the label to show a description of the checkbox value you can put that in the `title` attribute and read it back out. Try this:

```js
$('.rating label').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('div.rating').find('.hover-score-label').show().text($(this).prop('title'));
}, function() {
  $(".click-score.scored").show();
  $(".hover-score-label").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-control description">
  <fieldset class="rating-fieldset">
    <legend class="sr-only">Rating</legend>
    <div class="rating-container">
      <div class="rating">
        <span class="click-score hide" dir="ltr"></span>
        <div>
          <label title="Worst">
            <input type="checkbox" id="star1" name="rating" value="1">
            <span>★</span>
          </label>
          <label title="Bad">
            <input type="checkbox" id="star2" name="rating" value="2">
            <span>★</span>
          </label>
          <label title="Average">
            <input type="checkbox" id="star3" name="rating" value="3">
            <span>★</span>
          </label>
          <label title="Good">
            <input type="checkbox" id="star4" name="rating" value="4">
            <span>★</span>
          </label>
          <label title="Best">
            <input type="checkbox" id="star5" name="rating" value="5">
            <span>★</span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <span class="hover-score-label hide" dir="ltr"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer. There is still a problem when you duplicate the whole code to make another rating section. The two rating section are linked although they should not be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've used your code but somehow the hover-score-label shows 11,12, 13, 14, 15 instead of 1,2,3,4,5 like in your snippet.

Also I dont really know what this piece of code does:

var score = $(".rating label").length - $(this).index('.rating label');

Comment: Also, I want to have text instead of the 1 till 5 score. Maybe it was a bit dumb of me to use the numbers in my example but I actually want scores like: Worst - bad - avarage - good - best

Comment: The first issue may bee to do with the indexes of your elements in the actual HTML. However as you want to use textual values, that's moot. I edited the question to re-arrange the labels to surround the checkboxes to give a bigger hit area and also to include the text labels in the `title` attribute. Also note that I re-arranged the order, as ratings generally go from worst to best, left to right

Comment: Cool, thanks. Im going for lunch now and when I get back I will implement it in my code :)

Comment: Works great, now I only need to get the click-score label working and it is done. Im trying to do it with the same piece of code as the hover but no luck so far.